# Recent profile page changes lead to problems for unregistered users

Tags: bug, status-completed, network-profile, unregistered-users, 404-not-found

It looks like the profile page has been updated recently, e.g. the community list is now different when it's empty:

[image]

However, two things are 'off' for unregistered users:

1. It seems like users are never shown as unregistered anymore. I've checked half a dozen spammers from Metasmoke records, those are usually unregistered, but the word "(unregistered)" is displayed for none of them. **Update:** I found an [unregistered user](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/311510/retard) on English Language & Usage. So this might be just a bad sample.
2. The link to the network profile is shown (example: [this spammer](https://askubuntu.com/users/857444/vorablna12))

[image]

However, [that link](https://stackexchange.com/users/14106206/vorablna12) gives a 404.

Comment: Yep, also aggregator - thanks!